# How to convert value textbox type=number to decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a TextBox in an asp.net webform with the property type set to number, like this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Price" placeholder="Price" Type="Number" step=".01" />
```

I have a hard time converting its value to decimal as I always get an integer despite using a separator for decimals, example:

1.23 to 123.00

Comment: Where is the code of the conversion?

Comment: Yes, not working.
Here is the code of the conversion: 
decimal MyPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(Price.Text, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("it-IT"));

Comment: what value is Price.Text have at this time?

Comment: here is your problem: CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("it-IT")

Comment: `<asp:TextBox ID="Price" placeholder="price" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="Regex2" runat="server" ValidationExpression="((\d+)+(\.\d+))$"
ErrorMessage="Please enter valid decimal number with any decimal places." ControlToValidate="Price" />` have the user enter the decimal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is on the CultureInfo that you're passing for conversion, looks like the "it-IT" standard for decimals is using commas instead of dots. Here is an example:

```
var x = "1,23";             
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDecimal(x, new CultureInfo("it-IT")));
        
var y = "1.23";
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDecimal(y, new CultureInfo("it-IT")));
```

For your code work with the CultureInfo specified, you need to replace the dot to a comma on the time of conversion, or remove the CultureInfo specification at all and keep using dots.

Also, if you are converting this to show a price tag on display you can use this too:

```
Convert.ToDecimal("1,23").ToString("C", new CultureInfo("it-IT"))
```

Answer (score 0):

the thing is for `"it-IT"` "," is a decimal separator, when you send 1.1 will be treated as "1,1", in general client UI Client culture must be  same as server culture, if you really want to resolve this problem. Before the decimal conversion replace "." with comma. something like below. don't see any workarounds.

```
string textFormat = Price.Text.Replace(".",",");
        decimal MyPrice = 
       Convert.ToDecimal(textFormat, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("it-IT"));
        Console.WriteLine(MyPrice);
```